# Haskell - Bags - How can I use polymorphism in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

I have just started learning Haskell and still haven't grasped Functional Programming. I need to create a polymorphic datatype whose type I don't know until one of the functions I've written is run. The program seems to want me to build a list of tuples out of a list, e.g.:

`['Car', 'Car', 'Motorcycle', 'Motorcycle', 'Motorcycle', 'Truck']` would be converted to `[('Car', 2), ('Motorcycle', 3), ('Truck', 1)]`.

Within a same list of tuples (a bag), all elements will be of the same type, but different bags may contain other types. Right now, my datatype declaration (I'm not sure if it's called 'declaration' in FP) goes:

```
type Amount = Int
data Bag a = [(a, Amount)]
```

However, when I try to load the module, I get this error:

```
Cannot parse data constructor in a data/newtype declaration: [(a, Amount)]
```

If I change `data` to `type` in the declaration, I get this error message for all functions:

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘Bag’
Expected a type, but ‘Bag’ has kind ‘* -> *’
```

Is there something I'm not grasping about FP or is it a code error?, and more importantly,  how can I declare this in a way that actually allows me to load the module into GHCi?

Answer (score 8):

## Defining a `data` type

This is not about functional programming itself. If you define a `data`type (or `newtype`), in Haskell it needs a *data constructor* (for `newtype` there can only be *one* data constructor, and with one parameter). `[(a, Amount)]` is however *not* a good "name" for a data constructor (well you did not intend to use that as a data constructor anyway).

We can here write a data constructor like:

```
data Bag a = Bag [(a, Amount)]
```

and since here `Bag` contains (likely) one data constructor with *one* parameter, we can make it a `newtype`:

```
newtype Bag a = Bag [(a, Amount)]
```

The above however might not be necessary: you might want to declare a type *alias* with `type`:

```
type Bag a = [(a, Amount)]
```

in that case, you did *not* construct a new type, but you can write `Bag a`, and "behind the curtains", Haskell will replace this with `[(a, Amount)]`.

## Define functions with `Bag`

In case you now want to define a function that processes a `Bag`, you will need to specify the parameter `a` in the signature as well, for example:

```
count :: Eq a => [a] -> Bag a
count =  -- ...
```

Now it is clear that we transform a list of `a`s, in a `Bag` of `a`s.